# how get each single column data from php multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

how get each single column data from php multidimensional into single column array?

```
like $_test = = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1001,
        'first_name' => 'kalpesh',
        'last_name' => 'gamit',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 1002,
        'first_name' => 'kartik',
        'last_name' => 'patel',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2002,
        'first_name' => 'smith',
        'last_name' => 'Jones',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 4004,
        'first_name' => 'patel',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    )
);
```

want result like id OR first_name only without use loop like while, foreach, for etc

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1001
    [1] => 1002
    [2] => 2002
    [3] => 4004
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update your script like below and check it please but it will work only in **PHP 5.5 greater than version only**...

```
 $_test = = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1001,
        'first_name' => 'kalpesh',
        'last_name' => 'gamit',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 1002,
        'first_name' => 'kartik',
        'last_name' => 'patel',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2002,
        'first_name' => 'smith',
        'last_name' => 'Jones',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 4004,
        'first_name' => 'patel',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    )
);

$ids_only = array_column($records, 'id');
print_r($ids_only);
```

Results for ID

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1001
    [1] => 1002
    [2] => 2002
    [3] => 4004
)
```

Results for first_name

```
$first_name = array_column($records, 'id');
print_r($first_name);
Array
(
    [0] => Kalpesh
    [1] => kartik
    [2] => smith
    [3] => patel
)
```

run above php script and please check....

Answer (score 0):

You could use **[array_map](http://php.net/array_map)**:

```
$id_list = array_map(function($var) {
  return $var['id'];
}, $_test);
```