# Convert Array of Objecta to single array using only the value

Tags: php, arrays

How can I convert and object like this:

```
Array(
   Object(
       'id' => 1
   ),
   Object(
       'id' => 2
   ),
   Object(
       'id' => 3
   ),
)
```

To and array like this:

```
Array(1,2,3)
```

Without using a for loop. Is there some pre-built function in php to accomplish that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how get each single column data from php multidimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368491/how-get-each-single-column-data-from-php-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built in function in PHP is `array_column`

```
$ids = array_column($array, 'id');
```

It will fetch all ids from the inner objects/associative arrays and put them in a unidimensional array.

```
$ids = [1, 2, 3];
```